# Mixing AMD and Nvidia graphics cards in Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, ati

This question has been asked before, albeit within the context of a Windows 7 environment.

**Is it possible to run AMD and Nvidia graphics cards concurrently in a linux (Ubuntu 12.10) environment? If so, how?**

Ideally, one (Nvidia) would be used for its intended purpose--driving the display--and the other (AMD) would be used for computation.

Comment: If it's possible on windows then there is no reason it wouldn't be possible Linux