# NVIDIA GPU1 AMD GPU2. Cant get both drivers to work together on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, amd-graphics

I am trying to set up ubuntu 16.04 to use an amd gpu and a Nvidia gpu at the same time. The amd gpu is a R9 390x and Nvidia a 1070 GTX.

I have been able to install each driver seperatly with one card in at a time without a problem but getting them to work together has been a big problem.

I wish to use the nvidia for display and crypto mining while the amd card just for mining.

I have tried using the instructions from this link :
[NVIDIA card for CUDA and AMD card for display on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892532/nvidia-card-for-cuda-and-amd-card-for-display-on-ubuntu-16-04)
But it is using the cards the other way round (AMD for display) and even after following the instructions (but installing the AMD card first and NVIDIA last), I am logged out after trying to log in once I've installed the second/NVIDIA GPU.

Ideally a guide on how to install the AMD driver and then the NVIDIA driver on 16.04 and still have use of both cards (Nvidia as display) is what I need.

It works fine on windows 10 but I haven't had any luck getting them both to work at the same time on Ubuntu even on previous distributions.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

1. Assuming no drivers installed and no GPUs installed in computer
2. Add AMD GPU to computer, launch Ubuntu
3. Install amdgpu-pro driver
4. Install nvidia driver (for example via `sudo apt install nvidia-384`)
5. Shutdown computer
6. Add NVidia card to computer, launch Ubuntu
7. Switch to console mode via `Ctrl+Alt+F1`
8. `sudo nvidia-xconfig`
9. `sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
10. Comment or delete all lines except Monitor, Device and Screen sections (edit under root). Example result:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

10. `lspci | egrep -h "VGA|3D controller"` - remember identifiers at the beginning of each line:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii XT [Radeon R9 290X] (rev 80)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK110 [GeForce GTX TITAN] (rev a1)
```

11. `sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf` and use these identifiers:

```
Section "Monitor"
    ... no changes ...
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusId          "PCI:2@0:0:0" # Add this line (identifier 2 taken from lspci output on the previous step)
EndSection

# Add similar section for AMD card:
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "amdgpu"
    BusId          "PCI:1@0:0:0" # Identifier 1 taken from lspci output
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"     # This identifier should be from the GPU device connected to display (you need NVidia, so it is Device0) 
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

12. Shutdown
13. Connect display to NVidia card
14. Launch Ubuntu - everything should work

If it doesn’t work - please provide output of `lspci | egrep -h "VGA|3D controller"`, your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

P.S. somebody please guide me how to properly "post" this answer for these similar questions:

- [Mixing AMD and Nvidia graphics cards in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359441/mixing-amd-and-nvidia-graphics-cards-in-ubuntu)
- [How do I get both an AMD and NVidia GPU to not crash lightdm or hang on startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998174/how-do-i-get-both-an-amd-and-nvidia-gpu-to-not-crash-lightdm-or-hang-on-startup)
- [Setting up CUDA on NVIDIA and AMD GPU system, starting lightdm removes nvidia binaries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005159/setting-up-cuda-on-nvidia-and-amd-gpu-system-starting-lightdm-removes-nvidia-bi)
- [Using both nvidia and amd gpu in the same machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924071/using-both-nvidia-and-amd-gpu-in-the-same-machine)