# Trying to get two GPUs working in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, amdgpu

I'm having a very difficult time getting two GPUs to work. I have GeForce GT 630 that is working and I have installed a Pegatron AMD Radeon HD6450. Which shows when running sudo lshw -C display. I can install fglrx_14.201.deb from AMD and get that to show in additional drivers list but cannot get the video card to show in monitors and get anything on display. I want to run two monitors off the 1GB AMD card for TVs and have 1 monitor for the 2 GB card for games. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NVIDIA GPU1 AMD GPU2. Cant get both drivers to work together on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947679/nvidia-gpu1-amd-gpu2-cant-get-both-drivers-to-work-together-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: I know how to wipe out the Nvidia drivers, but how can I check for and wipe out any other video drivers? After that I'll try setting up just the AMD card first; following the procedure listed above. I've been using the Nvidia card this whole time.